# how draw root locus in mathematica 9 for a special case

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, root

my closed loop transfer function is:

```
H(s)=2exp(-q)/(1+exp(-2q)) 

q=sqrt((a+k sqrt(s)+s)*s) ,  s=sigma+jw
```

how can i draw root locus of H(s) as 'a' changes for different values of k?
i need a code for mathematica 9,i have examined some codes, but they didn't work.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RootLocusPlot.html

Comment: it is just for analytical transfer functions!! so it is not appropriate for my transfer function.

Comment: I'd suggest mathematica.stackexchange.com. Please use mathematica syntax so people who want to help can cut paste your code.